# Unique Slug Generator

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add a slug field, Here's what I tried in my model,

```
slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)



def pre_save_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):

   slug = slugify(instance.title)
   exists = Data.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists()
   if not exists:
      instance.slug = slug
   else:
      instance.slug = "%s-%s" % (slug, instance.id)



pre_save.connect(pre_save_receiver, sender=Data)
```

Problem is that it's adding the ID in slug field behind title no matter even if it's a very Unique title. 
How can I fix that? Thank YOU :)

Answer (score 1):

The signal always runs pre-save, even when you're updating an already-existing instance. And if you are updating, then a query for the slug will return an existing instance: that is, the one you are updating. You need to exclude the current one in that case.

```
query = Data.objects.filter(slug=slug)
if instance.pk:
    query = query.exclude(pk=instance.pk)
if query.exists():
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Model at least has the following:

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    title   = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug  = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)
```

You need to create a file named utils in your app folder which contains the following code:

**utils.py**

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

def random_string_generator(size=10, chars=string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

def unique_slug_generator(instance, new_slug=None):
    if new_slug is not None:
        slug = new_slug
    else:
        slug = slugify(instance.title)

    Klass = instance.__class__
    qs_exists = Klass.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists()
    if qs_exists:
        new_slug = "{slug}-{randstr}".format(
                    slug=slug,
                    randstr=random_string_generator(size=4)
                )
        return unique_slug_generator(instance, new_slug=new_slug)
    return slug
```

**Models.py**

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, post_save

from .utils import unique_slug_generator

def pre_save_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
    instance.slug = unique_slug_generator(instance)

pre_save.connect(pre_save_receiver, sender=YourModel)
```